# "Server is unreachable" when logging into GitHub with PyCharm

Tags: github, pycharm

I am trying to log into my `GitHub` through `PyCharm` and I get the following error:

```
"Server is unreachable."
```

Does anyone know what it means that the server cannot be accessed and how can be fixed?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: This usually means that there is no internet connection or an error in the url